# A hash function with predicted collisions

Tags: cryptography, hash

As far as I know, the more collision-resistant a hash function is, the better. But is there any way to define a hash function with *predicted* collisions? In other words, a hash function that collides for some known set of possible inputs and avoids collisions for other input values. To state the problem simpler:

Let $A$ be some set of strings. 
Define a function $f$ such that $f(x_i) \rightarrow y_i$ with $y_i \neq y_j$ for all $i,j \notin A$ with $i \neq j$, and otherwise $f(x_i) \rightarrow y$ where $y \notin \{y_i \mid i \notin A\}$ is constant.

Is it possible? In addition, is it possible for performance of such a hash function *not* to depend on the size of $A$?

Comment: @JeffE I'm not sure about the correct formulation, but I meant function with minimized probability of a collision.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is "uniform".

Comment: I'd say that it has to depend on $|A|$. I won't try to formalize this in an answer (for a variety of reasons, not least among which is that I don't know whether this argument makes any sense), but here it is. If $A$ is finite, then any membership check must check for string length (explicitly or accidentally) to exclude arbitrarily large strings. The length of the longest string in $A$ is bounded below by an expression involving $|A|$ and $|\Sigma|$, the size of the alphabet. So any condition(s) that, when checked, result in a finite $A$, must take time depending on $|A|$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally the collisions in a hash function are, in a way, what winds up improving the running time.

This is because running time (or size, or insertion time) is generally defined in terms of worst-case input.  If you use an algorithm without any randomness or hash, you need to deal with the worst case.  For example, finding duplicate elements in an array has an $\Omega(n\log n)$ in the comparison model, same as sorting.  But if you just hash the values, you can determine whether or not there's a duplicate in $O(n)$ time and space with a small probability of error.    Determining a hash function that wouldn't collide, eliminating the possibility of error, has to take $\Omega(n\log n)$ time.  (You may notice that these are, in a way, the same problem--though of course hashed values generally belong to a smaller universe and the comparison model may not be appropriate).

That said, there are some ways to take advantage of the ways hash functions collide.  One is [locally sensitive hash functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing), in which elements with small differences (i.e. normal distance functions for points) hash to the same value.  Recently I've been reading [this paper](http://www.siam.org/proceedings/soda/2010/SODA10_094_neylont.pdf)(1), which I found really easy to read, and shows some good, intuitive applications for how a locally sensitive hash function can be used to solve seemingly difficult problems--in this case the nearest neighbor problem with small probability of error.

Incidentally, the space advantage of possible collisions is how [bloom filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) work, a data structure that allows you to store elements of a set, each in space smaller than their actual size.  They are a constant factor away from optimal, and the upper and lower bounds demonstrate the tradeoff between error and space.

(1) Neylon, T.  A locally sensitive hash for real vectors.  SODA2010.

Comment: By the way. As far as I know, bloom filters still take $O(n)$ time, because the worst case is just a basic lookup. Is there way to speed things up?

Comment: @madfriend examples for what?

Bloom filters take $O(n)$ space and $O(k)$ time, where $k$ is the number of hash functions.  (This is slightly incorrect as it takes $k$ hashes, which are generally $w^{O(1)}$ where $w$ is the word size).  $k$ has nothing to do with $n$ and certainly should not be $O(n)$.